# How can I setup all VPN configs in a directory?

Tags: network-manager, openvpn

If you have a directory with VPN configs, how can you set them all up as part of the network-manager? I know how to do one by one, but I want to configure them all at once.

Comment: Care to tell us how you do one? ;-) I would assume the others would be 1 for loop :D

Comment: Well to be fair, I use the GUI of network-manager to do one. In other words, if there is a CLI alternative to add one to network-manager that would possibly solve the question.

Comment: ah like that. Have a look at `/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/`  There are files there named after the ssid's.